# Code optimization tool

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring, optimization

Would it be possible to develop a program that could optimize algorithms, detect design patterns and then rewrite the code? For example:

1. Detect a Bubble sort and transform it into a Quick sort or a Merge sort
2. Replace unnecessary repetitions of instances of a class into a Singleton
3. Refactor similar functions into a more generic one that accepts
   parameters

This program should be applicable to the sources of any programming language through configuration files containing the various rules such as grammar

Comment: Are these things an optimization? To optimize something, you first need something to compare with. Something to "improve". What are you improving here? Code quality? If yes, what would be the code "to compare with"? Why Bubble is worse than Quicksort if what you want to implement is a Bubble sort?

Comment: Almost no one who wants to sort things *writes* a sort algorithm. They *write* `(sort things)` and leave it to the language implementer to have written a good sort

Comment: @Laiv it was just an example, imagine that the programmer has implemented Bubble sort because he doesn't know a better sorting algorithm

Comment: Well, the "Optimizer" can not "imagine". It doesn't know if such an algorithm was written intentionally or not. And if yes, it doesn't know why.

Comment: Sure, but detecting that this algorithm could be rewritten in a more efficient way, it could suggest this optimization to the programmer who could accept or reject it

Comment: Who knows what artificial intelligence will bring us in the next 100 years? Maybe there will be some "artificial brain" which can do things similar to what a human can do in tasks like programming, maybe not. But what you are describing here is far from just "developing some program", and questions which are asking about predicting the future over the next 100 years are not a good fit for the main site, this is something better suited for our chat rooms.

Comment: The knowledge gap I always find pesky between optimizer and human beings is the nature of runtime inputs. I know what data sets are smaller usually than larger better than the optimizer, and I know the users tend to push this button more than that button. The optimizer knows better than me (unless I strain my brain a whole lot at least) how to do things like allocate registers efficiently. Until we can bridge this knowledge gap, a lot of the optimization is still up to me at some level -- at least with respect to algorithms and data representations.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible.

Deciding whether a program performs a certain algorithm (e.g. bubble sort) is equivalent to solving the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), and thus undecidable.

[Deciding whether two programs compute the same function is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1132167/2988), and thus undecidable. Deciding whether they perform a "similar" function will have similar problems.

Comment: This means it's not *possible 100% of the time*. It doesn't even mean it's impossible *most* of the time.

Comment: This answer is fully correct and netherthless completely missing the point.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, this is impossible *in general* due to the halting problem, as already stated.

Secondly, if it were possible, I wouldn't let such an optimizer do any of the things you suggest, so it's far from obvious that it would be any use.

> Detect a Bubble sort and transform it into a Quick sort or a Merge sort

This is a terrible idea. Bubble sort is *faster* than either quicksort or mergesort for sufficiently small inputs, it just scales up poorly. The programmer is better-placed to know the expected input size than a code analyzer.

> Replace unnecessary repetitions of instances of a class into a Singleton

Knowing when this is the correct thing to do requires understanding *intent*. It's not obvious how this will be visible in the code. Perhaps a singleton would be semantically correct, but I have chosen to keep one instance per thread for cache reasons. Perhaps I want to keep one instance for myself, and another one will later be shared with a dynamically-loaded library which is not visible at source analysis time.

> Refactor similar functions into a more generic one that accepts parameters

So now I have to also let it rewrite all my unit tests *and* trust that both the code and tests remain correct. *And* the generalized function will now put more pressure on my instruction cache and branch predictors, so may well perform worse.

Comment: To solve the "intent" problem, the tool could propose various optimization strategies and the programmer would decide whether to apply them or not. I know that such a program would be practically impossible but I am curious to know the opinion of the community.

Comment: Well, the question is asking, "if it's possible". Asking for opinions is off-topic and a good reason to get the question closed. The reason is simple, it turns all the answers into guesswork.

Comment: I knew I could be a little off-topic but this is one of the places where you can get the opinion of many experts and also I think it's an interesting topic

Answer (score 1):

Optimizing compilers perform program transformations every day, but they don't do it at the source level, and they need to do it in a semantics-preserving way. For example, loop unrolling and strength reduction are common techniques (which could even be applied to source code but may hamper readability.)

Refactoring can be done using tool support both in identifying places that might benefit from refactoring and in applying source code transformations. However, the decision and responsibility for the refactoring normally stays with the developers. In many cases, proving that a refactoring preserves the code's semantics is harder to do, and it's often a subjective judgement whether code is better readable and maintainable after such a refactoring.